# MySQL unique composite constraint not working

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, unique-constraint, unique-key, unique-index

I've created a unique index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE items 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX uni_item 
(warehouse_id, width, height, depth, weight);
```

but I still can add duplicate items, why is this not working?

Note:

The table itself also has some columns that are not included here, and warehouse_id is a foreign key, but these things shouldn't matter, right?

Thanks!

@cularis: here is the example of successfully added duplicates:

```
item_id, warehouse_id, width, height, depth, weight, date
1              4        100    100     100     14     2011-08-07 07:01:26


item_id, warehouse_id, width, height, depth, weight, date
6              4        100    100     100     14     2011-08-07 07:01:32
```

EDIT:

Adding more info as required:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
 `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `warehouse_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `width` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
 `height` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
 `depth` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
 `weight` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
 `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UNIQUE KEY `uni_item` (`warehouse_id`,`width`,`height`,`depth`,`weight`),
KEY `warehouse_id` (`warehouse_id`),
CONSTRAINT `items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`warehouse_id`) REFERENCES `warehouses` (`warehouse_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci






 INSERT INTO `main`.`items` (
`item_id` ,
`warehouse_id` ,
`width` ,
`height` ,
`depth` ,
`weight` ,
`date`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '4', 100, 100, 100, 14, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: could you show some inserts with duplicates you successfully added?

Comment: +1. I was puzzled with a similar situation recently. I changed the UNIQUE INDEX to a PRIMARY KEY and the problem went a way, but I did not understand why it did not work in the first place.

Comment: @Freelancer: give us ready to use script that reproduces the issue: `show create table` + 2 inserts, please.

Comment: @zerkms: I've added it, but just one insert, as they look exactly the same, not one single difference, but they still get into the database.

Comment: @Freelancer - In MySQL 5.0, I can't even run your CREATE TABLE statement: `Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key` :-?

Comment: it's probably a typo, just add primary key contraint on item_id

Comment: I commented earlier that I have seen this also. I researched further and it is actually not true: I got bitten by NULL values, see [Bug 8173](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8173) whereas you do not allow/have NULL values. Changing UNIQUE INDEX to PRIMARY KEY made me get rid of the NULLs (because PRIMARY KEY does not allow them) and thus my problem went away. Sorry about the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks very much for all the help.

Seems something was wrong with my installation, I've now reinstalled the whole server and the constraint works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not reproducible on mysql 5.1.58

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
 `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `warehouse_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `width`  decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
 `height`  decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
 `depth`  decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
 `weight`  decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
 `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `uni_item` (`warehouse_id`,`width`,`height`,`depth`,`weight`), 
 KEY `warehouse_id` (`warehouse_id`), 
 CONSTRAINT `items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`warehouse_id`) 
    REFERENCES `warehouses` (`warehouse_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `warehouses` (
 `warehouse_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `data` text,
 PRIMARY KEY (`warehouse_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into warehouses values (4, 'test');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

results in:

```
mysql> insert into items values (1,4,100,100,100,14,'2011-08-07 07:01:26');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> insert into items values (6,4,100,100,100,14,'2011-08-07 07:01:32');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '4-9.99-9.99-9.99-9.99' for key 'uni_item'
```

**EDIT**: use table definitions provided in question

Comment: I have 5.1.36, maybe it's even a bug, as snap (one of the posters above) had the exact same issue.

Comment: @Freelancer what if you try on your version with values of width, height, depth and weight that don't overflow the decimal(3,2) column? ie '1.00'

Comment: I wasn't even aware of that, shouldn't 3,2 allow me something like: 100.00?

Comment: @Freelancer it may be a bug indeed, but at a first glance i could not find any reference on that in the changelog for later versions. However it may as well be a collateral effect of another bug.

Comment: @Freelancer nope, left of decimal separator you get 3-2=1 digit; 3 is precision while 2 is scale